# Is there a way to use "<=" for pattern matching in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have the following code, that drops every nth element in a list.

```
dropEvery :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropEvery xs n = f xs n ++ dropEvery (drop n xs) n
    where
        f ys 0 = []
        f ys 1 = []
        f [] m = []
        f (y:ys) n = y : (f ys (n-1))
```

I would like to make it a bit shorter and was wondering if there is a way to use "<=" in pattern matching. I tried doing this using a `where` clause, which did not work, why?

```
f ys m = []
     where
         m <= 1 || ys == []
```

How can I shirk this redundancy? Is there a nice way to use "less or equal" in pattern matching?

EDIT: I tried this using guards

```
 where
     f ys m
        | m <= 1 || null ys = []
        | otherwise         = (head ys) : (f (tail ys) (n-1))
```

Comment: You can work with a guard.

Comment: Feel free to use guards, but don't use `head`, `tail` when possible. Use pattern matching instead, as Willem did below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a *guard*:

```
dropEvery :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropEvery xs n = f xs n ++ dropEvery (drop n xs) n
    where
        f ys i | i <= 1 = []
        f [] _ = []
        f (y:ys) n = y : (f ys (n-1))
```

If the condition in the guard is satisfied, then that clause "fires" and thus in this case will return an empty list `[]`.

You will however get stuck in an infinite loop, since you write `f xs n ++ dropEvery (n xs) n` but `drop 3 []` will return `[]`, and thus it will keep calling `dropEvery` with an empty list.

You can make use of recursion where we each time decrement `n` until it reaches `0`, and then we make two hops, so:

```
dropEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropEvery n = go (n-1)
    where go _ [] = []
          go i (x:xs)
              | i <= 0 = go (n-1) xs
              | otherwise = x : go (i-1) xs
```

We can also work with [**`splitAt :: [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) and with a *pattern guard*:

```
dropEvery n [] = []
dropEvery n ds
    | (_:ys) <- sb = sa ++ dropEvery n ys
    | otherwise = sa
    where (sa, sb) = splitAt (n-1) ds
```